# outputting a list of tuples to a new file in a certain format

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

let's say I have a list of tuples `my_list=[(who,2), (what,5), (where, 1)]`

I want to write in into a new file (new_file.txt) in this format:

```
who,2
what,5
where, 1
```

One above the other, with *no* brackets and only *inner* commas.

This does not work:

```
    with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as fd:
        a = '\n'.join(str(x) for x in results)
        fd.write('\n'.join(a))
        fd.close()
```

Will appreciate your help !

Answer (score 2):

```
results = [('who', 2), ('what', 5), ('where', 1)]

def line(u):
    return ','.join(map(str, u))

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write('\n'.join([line(u) for u in results]))
```

One note: you don't have to close the file explicitly, because `with` closes it for you.

If the `results` list is very long, you may not want to construct the file content in one go, but write them line by line:

```
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as fd:
    for u in results:
        fd.write(line(u) + '\n')
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to do it without map?

Comment: More elegant solution

Comment: `map(str, u)` is equivalent to `[str(x) for x in u]`

Answer (score 1):

You have converted the tuple to a string hence this might not work. A quick solution could be something like this assuming this is input data you are expecting:

```
results = [("who",2), ("what",5), ("where", 1)]

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as fd:
        data_str = ""
        for data in results:
            data_str += str(data[0]) + ',' + str(data[1]) + '\n'
        fd.write(data_str)
```